# Switching an array's elements in C

Tags: c, arrays, rotation, swap

So i want to switch the elements of an array with 32 integers "n" times.

All elements should be on the next position and the last should be at the first.

I tried something like this:

```
while(scanf("%d", &n) != EOF)
{
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++)
    for(int i=1; i<31; i++)
    {
        t[0]=t[31];
        tmp=t[i];
        t[i]=t[i+1];
    }
}
```

Im not sure how could I use the tmp variable to solve this problem.

this is the array's element:

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32

and it should look like this if the n=1:

32 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31

Comment: What do you mean by "switch"? Can you give an example?

Comment: You're storing t[i] in tmp but not doing anything with that value. Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with the rest of the code needed?

Comment: op means to rotate the elements, and not to shift them and even less switch them

Comment: If you draw the execution in paper, will help you. General at switching first store the `t[i]` in `tmp`and then make the switch

Comment: @DardaiIstvan please [edit] your question and put all clarificatins _there_ and not in an unreadable comment. And, yes, a piece of paper and a pencil are great tools for this kind of problems (for most problems actually)

Comment: @DardaiIstvan that's better, but consider formatting your question properly. It's very easy, just invest a few minutes to learn. Also consider to add the output for n = 3 or so, just to be sure. And you could boil down to 4-5 elements which would make it easier to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your swap is wrong, it should look like this:

```
char temp = t[i];
t[i] = t[i + 1];
t[i + 1] = temp;
```

Also, if you want an infinite loop like this, I recommend skipping whitespace in the `scanf`, like this:

```
while (scanf(" %d", &n) == 1) // note the space before %d
```

All in all, this is how it could look like:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char t[33] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456"; // 33 elements to leave space for '\0'
    int n;
    while (scanf(" %d", &n) == 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < 31; i++)
            {
                char temp = t[i];
                t[i] = t[i + 1];
                t[i + 1] = temp;
            }
        printf("string: %s\n", t);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this can be done without a temporary variable at all.

Comment: @Blaze thank you for your answer! it's working now!

Answer (score 2):

Following is not an edit of your code, but a more efficient solution with the runtime of O(n):

```
void rightshift(char array[LENGTH])
{
    int i, next = array[0];

    for (i = 1; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {
        char temp = array[i];
        array[i] = next;
        next = temp;
    }

    array[0] = next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the elements are shifted by 1 position each time, you could make it more efficient.
You don't need to use a temporary variable for each element but only for the first/last.
You do not need to swap each pair of adjacent elements.

```
void rotate_by_1(char array[], size_t elem)
{
    int i;

#ifdef ROTATE_LEFT
    // Rotate in one direction...
    char tmp = array[0];
    for (i = 0; i < elem-1; i++)
    {
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
    array[elem-1] = tmp;
#endif

#ifdef ROTATE_RIGHT
    // Rotate in the other direction...
    char tmp = array[elem-1];
    for (i = elem-1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }
    array[0] = tmp;
#endif
}
```

Not tested...

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that to rotate an array with *32* elements *n* times, you only need to rotate it `n % 32` times. As an alternative, which might not be the fastest, to the solutions already provided, the code below copies two chucks of memory of the original array in the reverse order which is equal to rightshifting an array *n* times.

```
#define LEN 32
#define NUMBER_OF_ROTATIONS 56

int array_to_rotate[LEN];

int* tmp = malloc(sizeof(int) * LEN);

int n = NUMBER_OF_ROTATIONS % LEN;

// copying the last n elements of array_to_rotate to the beginning of tmp array
memcpy(tmp, (array_to_rotate + LEN - n), n * sizeof(int));

// copying first (LEN - n) elements of array_to_rotate behind the elements already copied to tmp array
memcpy((tmp + n), array, (LEN - n) * sizeof(int));

//replacing the original array with the one obtained after rotation n times
memcpy(array, tmp, sizeof(int) * LEN));

free(tmp);
```